# Cannot retrieve text from website with selenium for python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to make a little program that gets the price of electricity each hour. it will retrieve the text displaying the price of the electricity.

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('-incognito')
option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
option.add_argument("disable-gpu")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=option)
browser.get('https://www.elektrikell.ee/')

hind = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/b')
```

Once i run it, it loads up the Webdriver and then crashes with the following error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/b"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

it happens to everything except the HTML , when i copy that Xpath, it works fine.
I enabled Javascript because i thought it might fix it, yet here i am.

Does python not support JavaScript based websites?

Comment: You may need to _wait_ for the element to load before you can find it (Yes, selenium supports running JS, regardless of Python doing so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the price text ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.elektrikell.ee/'})
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.priceHeader div.priceElement"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.elektrikell.ee/'})
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='priceHeader']//div[@class='priceElement']"))).text)
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  37.81
  senti / kilovatt-tund
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)